# solr query returning doclist of length 1, despite numfound being greater than 1

Tags: solr

When querying solr with a group-by field, I a response with "num_found" greater than 1, yet the "docs" attribute only shows 1 record.

The query is something like:

```
http://.../solr/.../select?q=*%3A*&fq=...&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=GroupingField_s&group.ngroups=true
```

The results are something like:

```
"grouped": {
    "GroupingField_s": {
      "matches": 3130,
      "ngroups": 283,
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupValue": "1111",
          "doclist": {
            "numFound": 7,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [ {/*only 1 record shown here*/} ]
         },
        {
          "groupValue": "222",
          "doclist": {
            "numFound": 5,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [ {/*only 1 record shown here*/} ]
        }, ....
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set the `group.limit` parameter. This defaults to 1.

> **group.limit** *integer* Specifies the number of results to return for each group. The default value is 1.

See [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping).